# PointerIndex out of range in native code?

Tags: android

Can you help me track down this stack trace - it doesn't seem to be in my code, or at least give me some tips of tracing the problem?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
    at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
    at android.view.MotionEvent.getY(MotionEvent.java:1989)
    at android.widget.FastScroller.onTouchEvent(FastScroller.java:854)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3024)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5564)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2052)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1813)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2058)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2058)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2058)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2058)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2058)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2058)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2058)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2080)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2058)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1931)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1390)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1879)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5766)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2890)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2466)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2475)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have various lists which it may stem from, and only one which uses the FastScroller. (If I am to assume this is the fast-scroll bar.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [the Android bug database entry](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18990)

This was happening to me when I was preventing all events from getting to the `ScaleGestureDetector` by filtering some out in an override of `ViewPager.onTouchEvent`.

Comment: I found a way to workaround the bug, I posted the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670970/viewpager-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-pointerindex-out-of-range/31459946#31459946